# ng-include directive and ng-controller option with variable

Tags: angularjs-controller

I have a question about using ng-include and ng-controller together. In the same element, the ng-include and ng-controller are at the same element, I take the url to do modification.

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Html Part:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div class="slide-animate-container">
      <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url" ng-controller="template.ct"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- template1.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    Content of template1.html {{boy}}
  </script>

  <!-- template2.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    Content of template2.html {{girl}}
  </script>
</div>
```

Javascript Part:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.templates =
      [ { name: 'template1.html', url: 'template1.html', ct: c1}
       ,{ name: 'template2.html', url: 'template2.html', ct: c2} ];
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
}

function c1($scope){
    $scope.boy = "batman";
}


function c2($scope){
    $scope.girl = "catgirl";
}
```

But I switch from template1 and template2, the template2 does not show me {{girl}} value properly, someone know why?

Thanks
Eric Xin

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use ng-switch and directives like [This Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

However the animation needs to be changed to work for the ng-switch

I prefer directives to ng-include